# How to return spinner selection?

Tags: java, android

```
package com.RaffDev.RaffApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;


public class RaffAppActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

/*Regular Variables*/
String copyright = "Raff App \n\nVersion: Alpha 0.0.1\n\n(c) Copyright Raff App contributors and others 2011. All rights reserverd";
MediaPlayer mp;
public int soundSelection = 0;


/*Called at the beginning of the application*/
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.soundEntries, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter); 



}

/*Button Functions*/
public void onClick(View v){}

public void infoClick(View v){

    Toast.makeText(this, copyright, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public void pressPlay(View v){
    switch(soundSelection){
    case 1: 
        if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) mp.reset();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.pleaseprettyface);
        mp.start();
        break;
    case 2: 
        if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) mp.reset();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.sheeesh);
        mp.start();
        break;
    case 3: 
        if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) mp.reset();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.heaintdodat);
        mp.start();
        break;
    case 4: 
        if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) mp.reset();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.thedousky);
        mp.start();
        break;
    case 5: 
        if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) mp.reset();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.nmouth);
        mp.start();
        break;


    }
}


/*Spinner Functions*/
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    soundSelection = (Integer) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
      // Do nothing.
}
```

}

Comment: I need a way to return which item is selected on the spinner. :[

Comment: spinner.getSelectedItem(),spinner.getSelectedItemId()

Comment: Try `soundSelection = Integer.parseInt(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is solution how to get selected item from Spinner**

```
public class YourItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
    // Do nothing.
}
}
```

for More Info Refer
[enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
`onItemSelected`
```

is returning you the position and using this position you need to extract the value. As you are using resource so you should get its value in your local variable and from their you can fetch the value....

Comment: Is it possible for you to show me an example? If it's not too much to ask. :[

Comment: get data in variable like this:   String[] var = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.soundEntries);   and String spinSelection = var[position]..

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if it's even possible to use a Switch for this.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use switch for fetching data from array......it will not be efficient ever....

Comment: So I'm guessing I should use if statements, correct? Sorry for all the questions, I'm still a little new to programming. Haven't done anything beyond beginner java and c++.

Comment: you got the selected item and do as per your need ...don't use if else or switch or anything else to get data ...you are getting the data in "onItemSelected" ...hope you got it or am i missing something then let me know.....

Comment: I meant the if statement as a method of using that data to decide which .mp3 is played.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing with the selected item .. You got the selected item and use it as per your need..if you want the to play the selected item then you can directly pass it to media player doing all this in a function and pass the selected item to it's argument..

Comment: I'm trying to make the app that plays a different .mp3 depending on the selected item.